# How do I open data on a new page?

Tags: javascript

I am making a weather app and want my weather data to open on new page but it's currently opening underneath the search bar. I want it to redirect to another HTML-page with the weather data from the Javascript code when I push the search-button. How do I do that the easiest way?

This is my Javascript code that gets the weather data: 
$(function() {

```
$("#city-form").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    search($("#city-input").val());
});

function search(city){

    $("#city").html("");
    $("#description").html("");
    $("#temp").html("");
    $("#humidity").html("");
    $("#wind").html("");

    var query = {
        'q' : city,
        'lang': 'SE',
        'units': 'metric',
        'APPID' : '31fb7e0aa1f90896809571484a8b13cc'
    };


    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
        type: 'get',
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
        dataType: "json",
        data: query,
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(JSON.parse(request.responseText).message);
            console.log(request.responseText);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // Logs server reseponse
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            // Sends data for presentation
            present(city, data);
        }
    });
}



function present(city, data){

    $("#city").html(city);
    $.each(data.weather, function(i, weather) {
        $("#description").append("<img class='w-icon' src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weather.icon  + ".png' />");
        $("#description").append(weather.description  + " ");
    });
    $("#temp").html(data.main.temp + " °C");
    $("#humidity").html("Luftfuktighet: "+ data.main.humidity + "%");
    $("#wind").html("Vind: "+ data.wind.speed + " m/s");


}
```

});

And this is my HTML-code with the search bar and weather data:

```
     <form id="city-form">
    <input type="text" id="city-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Sök på stad" required>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Sök</button>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>


<div id="weather">
<div id="city"></div>
<div id="temp"></div>
<div id="description"></div>
<div id="humidity"></div>
<div id="wind"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I think your question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you create another page that receives the city as a query param.

myPage?city="london"

Code for redirect:

```
    function search(city){
        window.location.href = 'myPage?city=' + city
    }
```

If you prefer open in a new tab: [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

On the new page you recover the city from params
[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

And do the ajax request the same way you do now, you gonna move the display info to the new page:

```
   <div id="weather">
   <div id="city"></div>
   <div id="temp"></div>
   <div id="description"></div>
   <div id="humidity"></div>
   <div id="wind"></div>
```

Comment: So if I want it to redirect to a html-page, can i write window.location.href = 'weather.htm'=' + city ?